# Mailchimp API : Batch Delete subscribers

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0, batch-delete

Is there any reference to the PHP warpper that I can use to perform batch delete subscribers. we have around 100k+ spam subscribers in Mailchimp list that we need to delete using batch delete.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the [PHP wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php) for API v2 or a third-party wrapper for API v3?

Comment: I want to use APIv3 and I dont found any PHP wrapper for APIv3

Answer (score 0):

There is no official PHP wrapper for API v3, but you can use third-party wrappers such as [this one from DrewM](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api). He has provided good documentation on how to use it.

Here is an example of how you can create a batch operation to delete (not unsubscribe) each spam address in the `$spamAddresses` array. Of course, you'd have to populate the array first.

```
<?php
include('mailchimp-api-master/src/MailChimp.php');
include('mailchimp-api-master/src/Batch.php');

use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
use \DrewM\MailChimp\Batch;

$apiKey = '********************************';
$listId = '**********';

$spamAddresses = [];

$MailChimp = new MailChimp($apiKey);
$Batch = $MailChimp->new_batch();

//Loop through array of spam addresses.
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($spamAddresses); $i++){
    $subscriberHash = $MailChimp->subscriberHash($spamAddresses[$i]);
    $Batch->delete("op$i", "lists/$listId/members/$subscriberHash");
}

//Execute batch operation.
$result = $Batch->execute();
echo $result['id'];
?>
```

Make sure to grab the batch ID that's stored in `$result['id']` if you want to check up on the status of the batch operation later, as [DrewM's example](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api#batch-operations) shows in his documentation:

```
$MailChimp->new_batch($batch_id);
$result = $Batch->check_status();
```